# Jenkins and Perforce password issue

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, perforce, maven-release-plugin

I'm using Jenkins with Perforce to build a maven project, and I need to use the maven-release plugin. I have configured my project and the build is going well, until I have tried to use the maven release plugin using the relevant Jenkins plugin. With dry run everything went well, but when trying to make the release I got this nasty error message (below). For some reason the Jenkins cannot connect to the P4 server. Also, the "Expose P4PASSWD in environment" is checked.

**Edit - answering Technext's questions**

- When you say dry run, do you perform it using Jenkins only or from command line? *Both*
- Where exactly are you setting the password for P4? In the 'Global credentials' section? *In the project configuration, under Source Code Management->Perforce->Password*
- Where are you getting the option of 'Expose P4PASSWD in environment'? *Same place*
- In the log above, is this line setting up the password for P4 `"d:\program files\perforce\p4.exe" set`? *This line exposes the P4 parameters - all of them (including P4PASSWD) are set correctly. I have removed the actual values from obvious reasons...*

This is the error message:

```
Started by user David 
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building on master in workspace X:\hudson\jobs\myproject\workspace
Using master perforce client: myproject
[workspace] $ "D:\Program Files\Perforce\p4.exe" workspace -o myproject
[workspace] $ "D:\Program Files\Perforce\p4.exe" login -a -p
[workspace] $ "D:\Program Files\Perforce\p4.exe" -P *** workspace -o myproject
Last build changeset: 1062732
[workspace] $ "D:\Program Files\Perforce\p4.exe" -P *** changes -s submitted -m 1 //myproject/...
Sync'ing workspace to changelist 1062732 (forcing sync of unchanged files).
[workspace] $ "D:\Program Files\Perforce\p4.exe" -P *** -s sync -f //myproject/...@1062732
Sync complete, took 108 ms
[workspace] $ cmd /c call D:\apache-tomcat-6\temp\hudson368187580614800030.bat

X:\hudson\jobs\myproject\workspace>"d:\program files\perforce\p4.exe" set 
P4CLIENT=myproject
P4PASSWD=***
P4PORT=***
P4USER=***

X:\hudson\jobs\myproject\workspace>exit 0 
Parsing POMs
Downloaded artifact ...
[workspace] $ D:/ins/Java/jdk1.7.0_10.x64/bin/java -DcreateChecksum=true -cp X:\hudson\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-agent-1.4.jar;X:\hudson\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\Maven_3.1.1\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar;X:\hudson\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\Maven_3.1.1/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main X:\hudson\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\Maven_3.1.1 D:\apache-tomcat-6\webapps\hudson\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-2.37.jar X:\hudson\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-interceptor-1.4.jar X:\hudson\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.4.jar 51470
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f X:\hudson\jobs\myproject\workspace\pom.xml -DdevelopmentVersion=0.0.2-SNAPSHOT -DreleaseVersion=0.0.1 -Dresume=false release:prepare release:perform -X
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 18:22:22+0300)
Maven home: X:\hudson\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\Maven_3.1.1
Java version: 1.7.0_10, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: D:\ins\Java\jdk1.7.0_10.x64\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows server 2008", version: "6.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from X:\hudson\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\Maven_3.1.1\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\...\.m2\settings.xml
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading: ...
[INFO] Downloaded: ...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] proj-parent
[INFO] proja
[INFO] projb
[INFO] projc
[INFO] test-reactor
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test-reactor 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare (default-cli) @ test-reactor ---
[INFO] Verifying that there are no local modifications...
[INFO]   ignoring changes on: **\release.properties, **\pom.xml.next, **\pom.xml.releaseBackup, **\pom.xml.backup, **\pom.xml.branch, **\pom.xml.tag
[INFO] No password found, proceeding without it.
[DEBUG] SCM path in pom: //depot/myproject
[DEBUG] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "p4 -p *** where X:\hudson\jobs\myproject\workspace\pom.xml"
[DEBUG] Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.
[DEBUG] cannot find depot => using //depot/myproject
[DEBUG] Executing cmd.exe /X /C "p4 -d X:\hudson\jobs\myproject\workspace -p *** opened //depot/myproject/..."
[ERROR] CommandLineException Exit code: 1 - Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.
```

**Edit 2 - Printing the environment variables**

Per Technext request, I've printed the relevant P4 environment variables when calling release:prepare. The variables all show the correct values (hidden here), but running thep4.exe afterwards claims that P4PASSWD is not set

```
[INFO] Executing tasks
Build sequence for target(s) `main' is [main]
Complete build sequence is [main, ]

main:
     [echo] P4CLIENT [myproject]
     [echo] P4PASSWD [***]
     [echo] P4PORT   [***]
     [echo] P4USER   [***]
[INFO] Executed tasks
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Join notifier requires a CauseAction
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test-reactor 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare (default-cli) @ test-reactor ---
[INFO] Verifying that there are no local modifications...
[INFO]   ignoring changes on: **\release.properties, **\pom.xml.next, **\pom.xml.releaseBackup, **\pom.xml.backup, **\pom.xml.branch, **\pom.xml.tag
[INFO] No password found, proceeding without it.
[DEBUG] SCM path in pom: //depot/myproject
[DEBUG] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "p4 -p *** where ***\pom.xml"
[DEBUG] Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.
[DEBUG] cannot find depot => using //depot/myproject
[DEBUG] Executing cmd.exe /X /C "p4 -d ****\workspace -p *** opened //depot/myproject/..."
[ERROR] CommandLineException Exit code: 1 - Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.
```

Comment: When you say `dry run`, do you perform it using Jenkins only or from _command line_? Where exactly are you setting the password for P4? In the 'Global credentials' section? Where are you getting the option of 'Expose P4PASSWD in environment'?  With the limited experience i had few years back with Perforce, i remember we used to have a setup where a schedular used to run every day for setting up the password on the build box. In the log above, is this line setting up the password for P4 `"d:\program files\perforce\p4.exe" set`?

Comment: Due to character limitation, i had to break my statements in parts. When you already have enabled 'Expose P4PASSWD in environment', why are you _again_ using `"d:\program files\perforce\p4.exe" set` command? Are you calling this _set_ command through a batch file or did you use the `Build > Add build step > Execute Windows batch command` section?

Comment: In any case, i see that just after the set command is executed, there is this line: `X:\hudson\jobs\myproject\workspace>exit 0`. This means the Windows batch environment (and the _variables set within that environment_), which is a sub-shell of the Jenkins build process, got completed.

Comment: After this, i doubt the variables (including `P4PASSWD`) will be present _unless_ 'Expose P4PASSWD in environment' is working fine. Can you try ECHOing the P4PASSWD variable just after the batch process completes?

Comment: @Technext I am using the "Execute Windows batch command" to run p4 set, I'm just doing it for debug purposes and would gladly remove it

Comment: Ok, got it. Can you try ECHOing the P4PASSWD variable just before the issue occurs and check whether it's set and in case it's set, whether it's correctly set?

Comment: @Technext see edit 2

Comment: Thanks for posting the details. The only try i can suggest you now is to try the `ticket-based` mechanism. I remember facing this issue in one of our job in the past. It was weird but specifying the ticket id instead of password worked. I recalled this after i checked this link just now: `http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Getting-ERROR-Perforce-password-P4PASSWD-invalid-or-unset-td3348364.html`. I suggest you give this a try.

Comment: @Technext thanks, but unfortunately p4 is run by the maven release plugin, which in turn run by Jenkins. If I run mvn release directly it works fine. This thread does not explain how to use the p4 ticket within Jenkins

Comment: You can check [this](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_passwd.html) and [this](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/chapter.superuser.html) link for P4 Ticket-based authentication. Once you generate the ticket on the given machine, you simply have to paste the ticket id in the place where you specify the password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got an solution. The Jenkins perforce plugin makes the login and issues a ticket, so I had to add `-Dpassword=${P4TICKET}` to the "Release goals and options" field. It causes the perforce SCM provider to run the p4 command with the `-P <P4TICKET>` flag.

Thanks @Technext for the assistance.

Comment: Glad to see that you finally got it working. Please mark your solution as answer so it can help others. :)